# Jquery Popup dialog, get submitted data - Fiddle Included

Tags: jquery, html

I have simplified the code I am using, but as you can see in my Fiddle, I Click a button to bring up a dialog with two inputs. When I press submit I have figured out how to get one of those inputs. with:

```
    $(document).ready(function() {
        $('#addthisquote').submit(function() {
            var input = $("input", this).val();
            alert(input);

        });
    });
```

http://jsfiddle.net/SteveRobertson/p6bCW/

How do I access each of those input individually?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can get those referring to their IDs

```
$('#description').val()
$('#price').val()
```

OR to their name attribute

```
$('input[name="description"]').val()
$('input[name="price"]').val()
```

Comment: awesome! thank you. I thought i tried that, obv did not. It says I Have to wait ten minutes to accept your answer, I will. Exactly what i needed though.